# Python function is only working once after the start of the server on Django

Tags: python, django

When using my Django page, I use a function that calculates the size of a folder during the run of a job, I am using that to display it on the page. But after some tests this function only works once after I run the server, after that it affects "0" to folder_size every time. I need it to work every time so I can affect the value to my model during the job. 
Do anyone have any idea about a way to solve that?

Here is the function :

```
def size_folder(folder_path):

    folder_size = 0
    print(folder_path)
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(path, file)
            folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
    folder_size = folder_size / (1024* 1024.0)
    if (folder_size < 1) : 
        folder_size = round(folder_size, 5)
    else : 
        folder_size = round(folder_size, 2) 
    folder_size = str(folder_size) + " MB"
    return(folder_size)
```

Comment: Can you show how you call the function? Where do you actually use this function to update the values in your model?

Comment: I call it like this      job2.size = size_folder("FILE/user_" + request.user.username + "/" + job2.output_name)     inside the views.py script, and the value job2.size is then sent to the template to be displayed.

Comment: Add any supplemental code to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55759805/edit), not to comments.

Comment: Either use a debugger, or add `print()` statements step by step to see where it goes wrong. Read all stack traces (and post them here is you need help).